# delete a specific row with where clause in sqlite for android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to delete a specific row with where clause in sqlite for android but it not working plz any body help.

```
public void delete(int p){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " ="+p);
db.close();}
```

Comment: Not working as in doesn't delete it? Or not working as in throwing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
public void delete(int p){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = "+p+"");
db.close();
}
```

Comment: adding a string add the end would fix it ?

Comment: the delete statement should be a string "DELETE FROM etc.. "  , here p is an integer, also I change getWritableDatabase() , to delete or update the database should be writable

Comment: thanx actually am new in android.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this `this.getReadableDatabase();`

to `this.getWritableDatabase();`

It should work.